# MPI asks authentication on localhost

Tags: localhost, mpi, multicore

I'm currently try to run an application on a single machine with 8 cores using mpirun -np 8.
The executables run fine and it actually uses all the eight cores of the machine for the tasks, but the problem is that it says that

```
    The authenticity of host '(name of the local machine) 127.0.1' can't be established.
    ECDSA key fingerprint is (fingerprint follows)
```

How can I avoid this problem? I guess this happens because MPI interprets each core as a node in a distributed cluster, is there some way to "tell" MPI that the cores are all on the same machine and therefore no authentication is needed?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

This isn't an MPI problem. You're using the incorrect IP address. You're using `127.0.1` when it should be `127.0.0.1` (or just `localhost`).

Also, make sure that you can `ssh` to `localhost` without requiring a password.

Comment: I was able to correct the problem of the authenticity: by running the program as root the system was able to write the host to the list of known hosts. But how can I stop it asking for a password?

Comment: You shouldn't be running as root. You should be able to do everything as your normal user. You need to set up passwordless SSH keys to get the authentication fixed.

Comment: I ran as root because normal user did not have permission to write to .../.ssh. I know that the right way would be to visudo the sudoers file and give the user the permission to read/write .ssh, but I just wanted a quick proof of concept. That worked and therefore, from now on, the host should be recognized even when the normal user runs the program. How do I set up a passwordless SSH key? Since that computer also receives external connections via SSH would that make also such connections passwordless?

Comment: There are tons (http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html, http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/, http://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/) of tutorials on the web for passwordless ssh logins. Give one of them a try.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but my problem is that I already login to the machine where I run the mpi program via SSH connection, logging in to the system as the same user that will use the mpi software. My fear is that, by generating another authentication key for the same user, I'll screw up my remote connection and end up locked out of the system...

Comment: SSH keys can be configured per user, per machine. You should set up a specific ssh key to go from the headnode of your cluster to the other machines on the cluster. That shouldn't impact logging in from your laptop to the headnode.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll give it a try. The thing is that is no such thing as a headnode in a cluster (or maybe I just don't know SSH terminology): the machine I connect to with my laptop it's the one who runs software with MPI on it's 8 cores, but they're all on the same motherboard on the same machine...